# Pygame File doesnt load

Tags: python, pygame, tetris

I recently finished building a Tetris game, it has no errors that I can see. When I run it in the text editor (Sublime), it runs perfectly fine and no errors populate.

But if I try to run it in the file itself on my desktop, It will only load the start menu screen but not the main game screen itself and exits the python program shortly after that. I do not see any errors from python before the program closes. Is there something wrong with my code in relation to the main tetris screen? I feel like I'm missing something but can't seem to tell what it is. I am brand new to coding and thought this would be a fun thing to surprise my coworker with as a gift. Thank you!

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.font.init()

s_width = 800
s_height = 700
play_width = 300  # meaning 300 // 10 = 30 width per block
play_height = 600  # meaning 600 // 20 = 30 height per block
block_size = 30

top_left_x = (s_width - play_width) // 2
top_left_y = s_height - play_height


# SHAPE FORMATS

S = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '..00.',
      '.00..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '...0.',
      '.....']]

Z = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.0...',
      '.....']]

I = [['..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '0000.',
      '.....',
      '.....',
      '.....']]

O = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

J = [['.....',
      '.0...',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '...0.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

L = [['.....',
      '...0.',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '.0...',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

T = [['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

shapes = [S, Z, I, O, J, L, T]
shape_colors = [(0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (255, 165, 0), (0, 0, 255), (128, 0, 128)]


class Piece(object): 
    def __init__(self, x, y, shape):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.shape = shape
        self.color = shape_colors[shapes.index(shape)]
        self.rotation = 0


def create_grid(locked_pos={}):  # *
    grid = [[(0,0,0) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(20)]

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if (j, i) in locked_pos:
                c = locked_pos[(j,i)]
                grid[i][j] = c
    return grid


def convert_shape_format(shape):
    positions = []
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                positions.append((shape.x + j, shape.y + i))

    for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
        positions[i] = (pos[0] - 2, pos[1] - 4)

    return positions

pygame.init()
def valid_space(shape, grid):
    accepted_pos = [[(j, i) for j in range(10) if grid[i][j] == (0,0,0)] for i in range(20)]
    accepted_pos = [j for sub in accepted_pos for j in sub]

    formatted = convert_shape_format(shape)

    for pos in formatted:
        if pos not in accepted_pos:
            if pos[1] > -1:
                return False
    return True


def check_lost(positions):
    for pos in positions:
        x, y = pos
        if y < 1:
            return True

    return False

pygame.init()
def get_shape():
    return Piece(5, 0, random.choice(shapes))


def draw_text_middle(surface, text, size, color):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", size, bold=True)
    label = font.render(text, 1, color)

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width /2 - (label.get_width()/2), top_left_y + play_height/2 - label.get_height()/2))


def draw_grid(surface, grid):
    sx = top_left_x
    sy = top_left_y

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (128,128,128), (sx, sy + i*block_size), (sx+play_width, sy+ i*block_size))
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            pygame.draw.line(surface, (128, 128, 128), (sx + j*block_size, sy),(sx + j*block_size, sy + play_height))


def clear_rows(grid, locked):

    inc = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)-1, -1, -1):
        row = grid[i]
        if (0,0,0) not in row:
            inc += 1
            ind = i
            for j in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    del locked[(j,i)]
                except:
                    continue

    if inc > 0:
        for key in sorted(list(locked), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
            x, y = key
            if y < ind:
                newKey = (x, y + inc)
                locked[newKey] = locked.pop(key)

    return inc


def draw_next_shape(shape, surface):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
    label = font.render('Next Shape', 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x + play_width + 50
    sy = top_left_y + play_height/2 - 100
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, shape.color, (sx + j*block_size, sy + i*block_size, block_size, block_size), 0)

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 3, sy - 60))


def update_score(nscore):
    score = max_score()

    with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
        if int(score) > nscore:
            f.write(str(score))
        else:
            f.write(str(nscore))


def max_score():
    with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        score = lines[0].strip()

    return score


def draw_window(surface, grid, score=0, last_score = 0):
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
    label = font.render('Tommys Tetris', 1, (255, 255, 255))

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width / 2 - (label.get_width() / 2), 20))

    # current score
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
    label = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x + play_width + 50
    sy = top_left_y + play_height/2 - 100

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 20, sy + 160))
    # last score
    label = font.render('High Score: ' + last_score, 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x - 200
    sy = top_left_y + 200

    surface.blit(label, (sx + -20, sy + 130))

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, grid[i][j], (top_left_x + j*block_size, top_left_y + i*block_size, block_size, block_size), 0)

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (top_left_x, top_left_y, play_width, play_height), 5)

    draw_grid(surface, grid)
    #pygame.display.update()


def main(win):  # *
    last_score = max_score()
    locked_positions = {}
    grid = create_grid(locked_positions)

    change_piece = False
    run = True
    current_piece = get_shape()
    next_piece = get_shape()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fall_time = 0
    fall_speed = 0.27
    level_time = 0
    score = 0

    while run:
        grid = create_grid(locked_positions)
        fall_time += clock.get_rawtime()
        level_time += clock.get_rawtime()
        clock.tick()

        if level_time/1000 > 5:
            level_time = 0
            if level_time > 0.12:
                level_time -= 0.005

        if fall_time/1000 > fall_speed:
            fall_time = 0
            current_piece.y += 1
            if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)) and current_piece.y > 0:
                current_piece.y -= 1
                change_piece = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    current_piece.x -= 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.x += 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    current_piece.x += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.x -= 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    current_piece.y += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.y -= 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    current_piece.rotation += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.rotation -= 1

        shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)

        for i in range(len(shape_pos)):
            x, y = shape_pos[i]
            if y > -1:
                grid[y][x] = current_piece.color

        if change_piece:
            for pos in shape_pos:
                p = (pos[0], pos[1])
                locked_positions[p] = current_piece.color
            current_piece = next_piece
            next_piece = get_shape()
            change_piece = False
            score += clear_rows(grid, locked_positions) * 10

        draw_window(win, grid, score, last_score)
        draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
        pygame.display.update()

        if check_lost(locked_positions):
            draw_text_middle(win, "YOU LOST!", 80, (255,255,255))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1500)
            return True
            update_score(score)


def main_menu(win): 
    run = True
    while run:
        win.fill((0,0,0))
        draw_text_middle(win, 'Press Any Key To Play', 60, (255,255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main(win)
                run = True

    pygame.display.quit()


win = pygame.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tommys Tetris')
main_menu(win)
```

There is also another file which saves the Highscore:

```
def update_score(nscore):
    score = max_score()

    with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
        if int(score) > nscore:
            f.write(str(score))
        else:
            f.write(str(nscore))
def max_score():
    with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        score = lines[0].strip()

    return score
```

Comment: Is there an error written to the console when it "exits [...] shortly after" ?

Comment: @Kingsley there is not, On my text editor screen it says: 
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[Finished in 4.4s]"

When I run it in python, It loads the start screen just fine, but when you go to the main game screen itll close out the program.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit hesitant in writing an answer in lieu of just entering a comment.  But, I wanted to share that I copied your program to a text file on my test system and ran the program.  The only way the program would not work was if the text file was not found or if the text file contained no score value.  Otherwise, it ran great.  Here is a snapshot of the program executing.

[image: TetrisGame]

I don't know what version of python you are running or what operating system you are running it on, but here are the specifications for my system and version of python:

- OS: Linux Mint version 20.3 (Una)
- Python version: 3.8.10
- Pygame version: 2.1.2

So my suggestions would be:

- Check on your version of pygame and python
- Make sure your text file exists and that it has a numeric score value

I don't know the characteristics of your text editor, but possibly you might try another text editor (e.g. "Notepad++" as that is available for various OS's).

Hope that helps.

Regards.